# 19th century Latin textbooks?

Tags: new-latin, resource-request, pedagogy

What textbooks were used to teach Neo-Latin in primary, secondary, and higher education schools during the 19<sup>th</sup> century?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The late 19<sup>th</sup> century primarily used grammar books for teaching Latin.

Latin was used for all subjects (including recess time!) as late as the end of the 18<sup>th</sup> century in France. Physics was first taught in French in 1783; cf. [Lucien Gagne, C.Ss.R.'s preface](https://cerclelatin.org/assets/uploads/files/Most-Coulombe_1re_annee.html#preface) to [Victor Coulombe's transl.](https://cerclelatin.org/wiki/Most-Coulombe/sommaire) of [Fr. William Most](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/most/)'s [*Latin by the Natural Method*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_list&search=authors:%22%3DMost%2C%20William%20G.%2C%20Ph.D.%22).

In the 13<sup>th</sup>-16<sup>th</sup> centuries, all oral lectures *and* textbooks for *all* subjects for children 6-14 were *entirely* in Latin, despite it not having been a vernacular for almost a millennium.

See:

- Ganss, George E., S.J., "[Appendix 1: **A Sketch of the History of Latin Teaching**](https://isidore.co/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Zotero/storage/JYQBE288/Ganss%20-%201954%20-%20Appendix%201%20A%20Sketch%20of%20the%20History%20of%20Latin%20Teach.pdf)." In [*Saint Ignatius' Idea of a Jesuit University a Study in the History of Catholic Education, Including Part Four of the Constitutions of the Society of Jesus*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=7887), 218-58. Milwaukee: Marquette University Press, 1954.

  - cf. the foreword of [*Latin by the Natural Method* (vol. 1)](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=5904) for a summary.

Comment: Interesting.  However, if you had the answer all by yourself, why ask the question?

Comment: @CMonsour I didn't know the answer at the time I asked the question, and no one else posted an answer. [Answering one's own questions is encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/257345) on StackExchange.

Comment: Cool. Thanks, I hadn't known that!